# Adding to a HTML text field by clicking items in a multiple select box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

I'm wondering if it is possible that when I click on an item in a multiple select box in HTML that it goes into another form box? Basically, when I click on something I want that text to go into a form. I've tried searching, but nothing seems to have an answer.

```
<form name="input" method="post" action="#">
Display Tag:<input type="text" name="taginput">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
<select name="tags" multiple>
    <option value="C#">C#</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Android">Android</option>
    <option value="jQuery">jQuery</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
</form>
```

To give an example, when I click on the `Java` option, I want `Java` to go into the input box called `taginput`. If I then click on the `Python` option, I want `Java Python`. Is this possible?

Comment: http://lab.artlung.com/dropdown/

Comment: When you click on multiple items in that select box, do you want all of them to go into that text field?

Comment: @andi Yeah, if I clicked on HTML then Java I'd want them both to go into that field, and also to be able to type in it myself.

Comment: You can do this using jquery: 
Simply by checking the selected item:
Check this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/85/

Comment: @VincentCohen That works, but I don't want it to be replaced, instead I want it to be added on to the previous one.

Comment: Type it in yourself too?  So how would that affect which options were selected?  i.e. what if the user selected Java and HTML, and then typed in "Peanuts" in the input?

Comment: @DogeDogeson I have update the jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/85/

Comment: @andi O'd want it to display "Java HTML Peanuts" in the input.

Comment: @VincentCohen That doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I think you are going to end up with a lot of weird cases if you let the user type into the text box but also try to match it up with the select.  Like, if the user deletes an option straight in the text box, should it unselect itself in the select box?

Comment: @DogeDogeson Sorry, wrong link. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/87/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, with **plain javascript**:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByName ('tags')[0];
sel.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementsByName ('taginput')[0].value = this.value;
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wDJLW/1/)**

**A second version** avoiding duplicates:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByName('tags')[0];
var choosen = [];
sel.onclick = function () {
    var is_there = !!~choosen.indexOf(this.value);
    if(is_there){return false;};
    choosen.push(this.value);
    document.getElementsByName('taginput')[0].value += this.value + ' ';
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wDJLW/2/)**

Comment: How could I make it so that it adds on to the tags instead of replacing them? For example, if I clicked Java then HTML I'd want it to add it on so that it looks like "Java HTML".

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it! Thanks :D

Comment: This creates duplicate content if you click on the same option more than once. Also, if a single option is selected, then also its added to the current value of text box, which should be replaced.

Comment: @Sergio, That doesn't work - I clicked on Java AND JavaScript, but the text box said "Java Java".

Comment: @andi, did you check the version in the comments? this: http://jsfiddle.net/wDJLW/1/

Comment: @DogeDogeson, if this is the functionality you are looking for I suggest you look at this: http://plugins.jquery.com/select2/

Comment: @Sergio It also adds tag into the dictionary I put it into, it's almost flawless but that still happens. Do you have a fix?

Comment: @DogeDogeson, I used `getElementsByName` do get the input field. Give the other element a different name or give them both an ID and use `getElementById` instead. Can you post the whole html?

Comment: It's ok, I've trimmed whitespace off the end of the results and it works now.

Comment: @DogeDogeson, great. You can accept the answer if it was what you were looking for. Check also this in case it might be useful: http://plugins.jquery.com/select2/

Comment: @Sergio - yes, that's the version I was looking at and it's not working for me.

Comment: @Sergio could you edit your answer so that it includes the link that works? Thanks.

Comment: @DogeDogeson, just did that. Glad I could help!

Comment: @DogeDogeson, updated with a second version also, in case you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, it finds the selected options, creates an array of text, then adds it to the text input.

```
$("select[name=tags]").change(function() {
    var arrSelected = $(this).find("option:selected").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    $("input[name=taginput]").val(arrSelected);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SyAN6/

Comment: It's not adding them on, I should have specified that... but it works, Sergio and VincentCohen have already posted working examples.

Comment: I mean when I click on multiple it should add the other one I clicked on onto it as well, so there would be multiple words in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/ppSv4/

```
$('select option').on('click',function(){
    $('#texthere').val( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

Comment: Would it be able to add another tag on instead of replacing them each time?

Comment: you can do this so...   $('#texthere').val( $('#texthere').val() + ' ' +  $(this).attr('value') );

Comment: but i think it's a bad idea : you should check for the selected items during each click. because, if you remove items...    Sergio response is a better start of way...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery, simply by checking for a change in the multi select box and then adding the newly changed data to the input field.

You can also the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/85/

```
$("#values").change(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#values option:selected");
    $("#txtRight").val( $("#txtRight").val() +  selectedItem.text());
});
```