# how to add multiple items from the list and add it to text field. and also i want to add item by typing in the input field

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-4

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" >
           <div class="form-group col-md-5" >
                  
                  <label for="skill">Skill</label>
                  <input type="text" name="skill" class="form-control">
                      <select multiple class="form-control" name="taqinput">
                      <option>css</option>
                      <option>html</option>
                      <option>c++</option>
                  </select>

              
              </div>
</form>
```

for example if i click on css the css will add into inputfield and also when i write math in the input field it will also be added.

Comment: I seen you have `select` and `input` tags, do you mean you want to add the value of select option to input value? If yes, you may want to use change or click event to handle that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788703/adding-to-a-html-text-field-by-clicking-items-in-a-multiple-select-box

Comment: @HarrisonO yes i want to add the select option in the input value